# Как хранить куки в переменной

Tags: html, typescript, angular

У меня есть переменная, которая будет хранить только два значения: true, false. Она нужна для того, чтобы узнать авторизирован ли пользователь или нет. Она так же, я так предполагаю, должна быть куки, ибо после перезагрузки страницы всё слетает. Я искал способ для изменения данных в куки, но тоже не нашел. К сожалению, не могу реализовать это. Помогите или подскажите с реализацией.

ts:

```
export class AuthorizationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cookie:CookieService) {}

  authorizationStatus = this.cookie.set("status","false");

 loginUser(user:Users){
    
    for (var i of this.logindb)
    {
      if (i.phone == this.loginconfirm.phone && i.password == this.loginconfirm.password) {
        console.log("ok");
       

        this.authorizationStatus = this.cookie.set("status","true");


      }
}
```

html:

```html
<li *ngIf="authorizationStatus ==='false'">
  <svg type="button" class="bi-person" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#UserModal">
</svg>
</li>
<li *ngIf="authorizationStatus ==='true'">
  <svg type="button" class="bi-person" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#UserModal1">
</svg>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Можно хранить не в cookie, а в localStorage или sessionStorage.

```
//set
sessionStorage.setItem('status', true);
localStorage.setItem('status', noOfClicks);

//get
sessionStorage.getItem('status');
localStorage.getItem('status');
```

2. Для того, чтобы получать данные, нужно использовать метод get, а не set

```
authorizationStatus = this.cookie.set("status","false");
```

В данном случае, вы получаете скорее всего `undefined`, так как скорее всего метод set имеет тип void.